# Link to a another page from a dynamic page in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I created a dynamic page by taking data from the database.

Example: `example.com/post/SE12`

This `/SE12` is dynamically created. Now I have a button in this page where I want to edit the post.

`example.com/post/SE12/edit`.

How can I link a button to this page using laravel? and how can I route this page and call it in controller?

In route.php

```
    Route::resource('posts','PostsController');
    Route::get('/posts/{code}', [ 'as'=>'post-show', 'uses'=>'PostsController@show']);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**routes.php:**

```
 Route::get('post/{code}/edit', [ 'as'=>'post-edit', 'uses'=>'PostsController@edit']);
```

**Controller:**

```
public function edit($id)
{
    echo $id; //this will give the code. e.g. SE12
}
```

**View:**

```
<a href="{{route('post-edit',[$post->id])}}">some title </a>
```

N.B. you are `resource controller` and `manual mapping` at the same time. stick to either one as much as possible. otherwise routes will get conflict.

Comment: Also, what if I want to update this page? 
I gave `{{Form::open(['url'=>'posts/'.$code.'/update'])}}`  for the form and in the route: `Route::get('/posts/{code}/update', [ 'as'=>'post-update', 'uses'=>'PostsController@update']);`

and in the controller
` public function update($code){
        return 'done';
    }`

But it is not working

Comment: Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Comment: Tried even this: 
`{{Form::open([URL::action('post-update', $post->code)])}}`

Comment: Route should be
Route::post('/posts/{code}/edit', [ 'as'=>'post-update', 'uses'=>'PostsController@update']);